# Filter R dataframe by another dataframe using a tolerance?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two data frames (A & B) of different lengths. For a given value in A, I want to know if there are values anywhere in B that are within a tolerance of +/- 0.3. It would also be useful to know the position of this value in B.

```
A<-c(1:10)
B<-c(2.2,15,1.8,4.9,20,14,8.2,33,9.8,41,16)
```

i.e for A[1] there is no value in B within the tolerance,

but for A[2], the values at B[1] and B[3] are within the tolerance,
and so on.

I have experimented with the *near* function in dplyr, however I can only seem to get it to compare on a row by row basis. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `between`

```
library(purrr)
map(A, ~  B[between(B, .x - 0.3, .x + 0.3)]) %>% 
     flatten_dbl
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one idea. `result` is a list. If there are no any match, the length of the element in the `result` is 0. Otherwise, `result` will document the index in B that matches the requirement.

```
A <- 1:10
B <- c(2.2,15,1.8,4.9,20,14,8.2,33,9.8,41,16)

difference <- list()

for (i in 1:length(A)){
  difference[[i]] <- B - A[i]
}

result <- lapply(difference, function(x) which(x < 0.3 & x > -0.3))
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this for a pair of values in two columns? i.e For values in the same row of columns AX and AY, find values of BX and BY (in the same row) that are within +/- 0.3. 

I have two data frames of x / y coordinates and am trying to find those that are near each other. @akrun

Comment: @forestsam I am sure there is a solution to your questions. You can post a new question with example datasets. People may help you.

Answer (score 0):

In base R, we can use `sapply` :

```
unlist(sapply(A, function(x) B[B >= (x- 0.3) & B <= (x + 0.3)]))
#[1] 2.2 1.8 4.9 8.2 9.8
```